# Application Nakayama's Lemma for Field Extensions $L \vert K$

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, dedekind-domain

I have a question about an argument  used in Tamas Szamuely's "Galois Groups and Fundamental Groups" in following excerpt (see page 96):

[image]

According the proof we firstly show that $\sum^r _{i=1} e_i [\kappa(Q_i): \kappa(P)]$ equals the dimension $n:= \dim_{\kappa(P)}B/PB$ of the $\kappa(P)$-vector space $B/PB$.

Then we take $t_1, ..., t_n \in B$ whose images in can projection $B \to B/PB$ form a $\kappa(P)$-basis of it.

By Nakayama (since $A_P$ local ring with maximal ideal $P$) these $t_i$ also generate the $A_P$-module $B \otimes _A A_P$.

What I don't understand is how does it imply that then the $t_i$ also generate $L$ as $K$-vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is by extension of scalars, because
$$(B \otimes _A A_P)\otimes_{A_P}K\simeq B\otimes_A K\simeq L.$$
The last isomorphism results from $B_P$ being finitely generated over $A_P$, $B\otimes_A K$ is finitely generated over $K$, and an integral domain, hence it is a field containing $B$.

Comment: @user26857: I've added some explanations.

Comment: Why is $B$ finitely generated over $A$?

Comment: @KarlPeter: Sorry, I meant  $B_P$ finitely generated over $A_P$. Fixed. Thanks for pointing it!

Comment: one point is still unclear. with your arguments we can conclude indeed that $B \otimes K$ is a field containing $B$. But don't we need also an argument that $B \otimes K$ is contained in $L$ to conclude $B \otimes K =L$?

Comment: The fiel of fractions of an integral domain is the smallest field containing the domain. Also, the injection  $B\hookrightarrow L$ gives by tensorisation the injection   $B\otimes_A K\hookrightarrow L\otimes_A K=L$.

Comment: Yes, you mean $L$ is the field of fractions of $B_P$ and $B$, right? That's indeed clear. So since $B \otimes K$ is a field we get $L \subset B \otimes K$. The unclear step is the other inclusion

Comment: Doesn't my last comment make it clear? On another hand, $B\otimes_AK$ is a ring of fractions of $B$ (with denominators in $A$).